# R: singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates

Tags: r, modelagem, regressão

Ao utilizar o seguinte comando para estimar os parâmetros do modelo (bell_model):

```
h <- c(43.34,   35.84,  33.45,  30.94,  27.35,  21.75,  13.75,  57.37,  
48.36,  44.62,  41.05,  36.49,  29.92,  21.07,  66.65,  56.65,  52.03,  
47.75,  42.54,  35.32,  25.92,  75.56,  64.60,  59.13,  54.17,  48.35,  
40.51,  30.57)
TR <-   c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20)
t   <- c(120,   60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 120, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 120, 
60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 120, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10)
dados <- data.frame(h,TR,t)

param <- list(a1 = 0.7, a2 = 0.38, a3 = 0.38, b = 0.31, a4 = 0.39)
bell_model <- nls(h ~ ((a1*log(TR)+a2)*(a3*(t^b)-a4)*41.59), dados, start = 
param)
```

Ocorre um erro:

```
Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) : 
singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates
```

O que seria esse erro e como resolver esse problema?
Desde já, agradeço!

Answer (score 1):

O erro `Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) : singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates` significa que o gradiente da procura pelas melhores estimativas para a tua equação é singular. ou seja, o determinante dele é igual a zero e, portanto, a matriz gradiente não é invertível.

As causas para isto são várias. Pode ser desde uma instabilidade numérica (pois a representação dos números reais nos computadores tem um número limitado de casas decimais) até chutes iniciais equivocados ou funções má especificadas. Eu optei por investigar a última razão para resolver o teu problema: funções má especificadas.

Tem certeza que o modelo a ser ajustado é `h ~ ((a1*log(TR)+a2)*(a3*(t^b)-a4)*41.59)`? Minha experiência diz que este modelo é muito complicado. É muito raro encontrar produtos de parâmetros da forma que tu colocou. Por isso, resolvi simplificar esta função pra ver o que eu achava.

Eu fiz umas contas aqui simplificando a tua fórmula e cheguei no modelo `h ~ (a1*a3*log(TR)*t^b - a1*a4*log(TR) + a2*a3*t^b - a2*a4)*41.59`. Assim defini

```
a1 = a1*a3
a2 = a1*a4
a3 = a2*a3
a4 = a2*a4
```

Por não ter produto entre parâmetros, me parece muito mais natural ajustar um modelo assim do que o modelo original. É mais natural pra mim e mais fácil pro computador, pois diminui a chance de ocorrerem instabilidades numéricas.

No final ficou assim:

```
param <- list(a1 = 0.7, a2 = 0.38, a3 = 0.38, b = 0.31, a4 = 0.39)
bell_model2 <- nls(h ~ (a1*log(TR)*t^b - a2*log(TR) + a3*t^b + a4)*41.59, 
dados, start = param)
summary(bell_model2)
Formula: h ~ (a1 * log(TR) * t^b - a2 * log(TR) + a3 * t^b + a4) * 41.59

Parameters:
   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
a1  1.26407    1.18903   1.063    0.299
a2  1.24840    1.20588   1.035    0.311
a3  4.43015    4.15081   1.067    0.297
b   0.04676    0.03749   1.247    0.225
a4 -4.69874    4.20360  -1.118    0.275

Residual standard error: 1.003 on 23 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations to convergence: 14 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 5.089e-06
```

Note que utilizei os mesmos chutes inicias do teu modelo e a minha tentativa encontrou uma resposta. Além disso, precisou de 14 passos até convergir, que é um valor razoavelmente pequeno.

Só tome cuidado: `a1` para mim, na minha parametrização, tem uma valor diferente de `a1` na tua parametrização. Se há um significado físico para este parâmetro, é bom ver como fazer a transformação matemática correta para obter o valor dele no contexto do teu problema. O mesmo vale para `a2`, `a3` e `a4`.

Comment: Olá Marcus, muito obrigado pela paciência e dedicação em responder
Sobre o modelo, ele é clássico e muito utilizado na literatura. É um modelo para estimar lâmina máxima precipitada, relacionado a uma duração (t) e a uma frequência (TR =1/f). Esse modelo já foi utilizado e ajustado para algumas regiões do brasil. A obtenção de parâmetros locais aumenta o poder de predição do modelo e por isso gostaria de obter esses parâmetros.
Usei os parâmetros iniciais me baseando nesses ajustes para outras regiões. Vou tentar uma abordagem relacionada ao chute inicial dos parâmetros para tentar resolver